# one key with multiple values Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
bag =('IAMDIETINGIEATQUINCEJELLYLOTSOFGROUNDMAIZEGIVESVARIETYICOOKRHUBARBANDSODAWEEPANEWORPUTONEXTRAFLESH__')
```

What should I do to make this input as below?

```
dic1 = {1: {'Q', 'Z', 'X', 'K', 'J'}, 2: {'F', '_', 'P', 'C', 'M', 'W', 'Y', 'B',   'V', 'H'}, 3: {'G'}, 4: {'U', 'D', 'L', 'S'}, 6: {'N', 'R', 'T'}, 8: {'O'}, 9: {'I', 'A'}, 12: {'E'}}
```

(occurrences as a key and correspond letters as a value)

What i have done so far is this

```
freq = {i:bag.count(i) for i in set(bag)} 
 {'U': 4, '_': 2, 'C': 2, 'K': 1, 'D': 4, 'T': 6, 'Q': 1, 'V': 2, 'A': 9, 'F': 2, 'O': 8, 'J': 1, 'I': 9, 'N': 6, 'P': 2, 'S': 4, 'M': 2, 'W': 2, 'E': 12, 'Z': 1, 'G': 3, 'Y': 2, 'B': 2, 'L': 4, 'R': 6, 'X': 1, 'H': 2}
```

I'm not sure about the next step

Thanks

Comment: First make a dictionary whose keys are the letters and values are the occurrences. Then loop through this to create the inverted dictionary.

Comment: StackOverflow expects you to [try to solve your own problem first](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592), and we also [don't answer homework questions](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6166). Please update your question to show what you have already tried in a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). For further information, please see [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and take the [tour of the site](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) :)

Comment: To get that dict, I'd put the data into a Counter. Then you just need to "invert" the keys & values in the Counter.

Comment: IAMDIETINGIEATQUINCEJELLYLOTSOFGROUNDMAIZEGIVESVARIETYICOOKRHUBARBANDSODAWEEPANEWORPUTONEXTRAFLESH WHATAMIEVENREADINGIHAVENOIDEA

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`collections.Counter` will give you a mapping from a item to a count.  Your requested data structure is a reverse of that mapping.  Here I use a `collections.defaultdict` to accomplish that reversal, grouping items with identical counts into sets:

```
from collections import defaultdict, Counter

s = 'IAMDIETINGIEATQUINCEJELLYLOTSOFGROUNDMAIZEGIVESVARIETYICOOKRHUBARBANDSODAWEEPANEWORPUTONEXTRAFLESH__'

d = defaultdict(set)
for k, n in Counter(s).items():
    d[n].add(k)
```

Comment: Aside from the value type (set, versus list) this looks like the better answer so far.

Comment: `ct.defaultdict(set)`  and `d[n].add(k)` will reproduce the OP's output.

Comment: @pylang: Good catch.  Updated to use `set`.

Answer (score 0):

You can count the frequencies, then group by the similar ones:

```
    from collections import Counter

    bag =('IAMDIETINGIEATQUINCEJELLYLOTSOFGROUNDMAIZEGIVESVARIETYICOOKRHUBARBANDSODAWEEPANEWORPUTONEXTRAFLESH__')
    frequencies = Counter(bag)
    
    dict1 = {}
    
    for k, v in frequencies.items():
        dict1[v] = dict1.get(v,[])+[k,]

                       
    print(dict1)
```

#### output:

```
{1: ['Q', 'J', 'Z', 'K', 'X'], 2: ['M', 'C', 'Y', 'F', 'V', 'H', 'B', 'W', 'P', '_'], 3: ['G'], 4: ['D', 'U', 'L', 'S'], 6: ['T', 'N', 'R'], 8: ['O'], 9: ['I', 'A'], 12: ['E']}
```

Comment: If you're already using `collections`, it seems silly not to use `defaultdict`